Copy data from worksheet to next row in another worksheet
I am trying to copy data from Product File to next empty row in FileMaster.
For example FileMaster is filled with previous data up to cell C50 and I want my data copied from cell C51 but is struggling with this.
My code is as below. It copies data from cell C2
Dim LastRow As String
FileMaster.Activate
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Workbooks("Product File.xlsx").Worksheets("data").Range("A2:N" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Workbooks("FileMaster.xlsx").Worksheets("new_template").Range("C2:N" & LastRow)
Application.CutCopyMode = False   


Range("C2:N" & LastRow) 

will always start form C2
you have to use
Range("C" & LastRow) 

but you'd better not relay on any "Active" object (be it a sheet or a workbook) and work with object direct reference
Dim LastRow As String
    With FileMaster.Worksheets("new_template")
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    End With
    With Workbooks("Product File.xlsx").Worksheets("data")
        .Range("A2:N" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy FileMaster.Worksheets("new_template").Range("C" & LastRow)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

or you can "shrink" it a little bit more:
    With Workbooks("Product File.xlsx").Worksheets("data")
        .Range("A2:N" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy FileMaster.Worksheets("new_template").Range("C" & FileMaster.Worksheets("new_template").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With


please consider using the coding style I'm suggesting you, and grasp complete control of the object you want to work on/with

Oh I found the solution =)))) For anyone who is struggling with the same problem you can refer to my answer as below
Dim LastRow As String
    FileMaster.Activate
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Workbooks("Product File.xlsx").Worksheets("data").Range("A2:N" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Workbooks("FileMaster.xlsx").Worksheets("new_template").Range("C" & LastRow + 1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False    'cancel the copy mode


the second Range reference, being without any parent worksheet explicit reference, is pointing to currently active sheet (which is a sheet of FileMaster workbook) instead of the Workbooks("Product File.xlsx").Worksheets("data") sheet. Please consider my answer code to ensure you're actually using the object you need
